# $f:R\to S$ and $f$ a ring epimorphism then if $1_S$ exists, then prove that $1_R$ exists.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R,S$ rings

$f:R\to S$ and $f$ Epimorphism then if $1_S$ exists, then prove that $1_R$ exists.

I wanna check if this statement is true or not.

Could anyone help me out with this once? I know from my theory that since $f$ is an epimorphism that $image_f = S$ but i dont know if that will be proven usefull or not.

Comment: @DonThousand im working on rings/subrings i dont know what a category is as for now.

Comment: Edit this question to make it clear you are talking about rings, There are lots of places where we talk about epimorphisms, and the tags is not enough to ensure your readers know what you are talking about.

Comment: Take $S$ to be the zero ring and $R$ to be any ring without identity. Then, $1_S$ exists but $1_R$ does not exist (assuming that they refer to the multiplicative identity elements of $S$ and $R$ respectively).

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang, is there a counterexample for which $S$ is nontrivial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't true.

Take $S$ to be a trivial ring, that is, a ring with only one element.
Then (trivially), $S$ has an identity: its only element.

Now take $R$ to be any ring without identity.
For example, $R = 2\mathbb Z$.
Then, the only map from $R$ to $S$ is surjective and thus, an epimorphism.

Note also that it's not always the case that an epimorphism is surjective, and you seem to assume that when you conclude that image of $f$ is $S$.
But perhaps you just use that definition.

---

**Added.**
Following a comment from [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews), I'll add an example in which $S$ is not trivial.
Take $f: x \mathbb Z[x] \to \mathbb Z$ defined by $f(xp(x)) = p(1)$.
It's easy to see that $f$ is a surjective homomorphism but of course, $x \mathbb Z[x]$ doesn't have an identity.

Comment: What about if $S$ has multiplicative identity $1_S \neq 0_S?$

Comment: @DylanC.Beck Then I wouldn't know immediately a counter-example. But that was not part of the question.

Comment: @amrsa thank you very much, you didnt only answer my question but now i also gotta search about the note you left me since thats what i assumed up untill this point.

Comment: For a non-zero example, $$x\mathbb Z[x]\to \mathbb Z\\xp(x)\mapsto p(1)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $x\mathbb Z[x]$ is the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients and null zero-degree term, that is, $$p(x) = a_nx^n+\cdots+a_2x^2+a_1x?$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, ah hah! I was very close on that trail, but I hadn't thought of that exact scenario. Well done.

Comment: @amrsa, that's one way to think about it. Another way to think about it is that $x \mathbb Z[x]$ is the ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$ generated by $x.$

Comment: @DylanC.Beck Thanks, I just wanted to confirm. It certainly works!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'll edit my answer to include that nice example of yours.

Comment: Possibly even easier non-null  answer is $2\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews And when you gave that first example, I was trying cases with $2\mathbb Z$ too, but didn't get one that worked, and then with your example, gave up. But indeed, this is even easier.

Answer (score 3):

@amrsa and @Thomas Andrews have already completely answered your question (+1), but here's another counterexample, which also shows that your claim that every epimorphism of rings is surjective is not true in general. Consider the inclusion $\iota:2\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$; I claim that $\iota$ is an epimorphism. To see this, suppose $g_1,g_2:\mathbb{Q}\to B$ are some ring morphisms such that $g_1\circ\iota=g_2\circ\iota$; we want to show that $g_1=g_2$. First note that, since $g_1(2)=g_2(2)$, we have
\begin{align}
g_1(1)&=g_1(1/2)g_1(2) \\
&=g_1(1/2)g_2(2) \\
&=g_1(1/2)g_2(1)+g_1(1/2)g_2(1) \\
&=g_1(1)g_2(1).
\end{align} By a nearly identical argument, we have $g_2(1)=g_1(1)g_2(1)$, whence $g_1(1)=g_2(1)$. Now let $a/b$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Q}$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\neq 0$. Replacing $a$ and $b$ with $2a$ and $2b$, we may assume that $a,b\in 2\mathbb{Z}$, whence $g_1(a)=g_2(a)$ and $g_1(b)=g_2(b)$. Now we have

\begin{align}
g_1(1/b)&=g_1(1/b)g_1(1) \\
&= g_1(1/b)g_2(1) \\
&=g_1(1/b)g_2(b)g_2(1/b) \\
&=g_1(1/b)g_1(b)g_2(1/b) \\
&=g_1(1)g_2(1/b) \\
&=g_2(1)g_2(1/b)=g_2(1/b).
\end{align}

Thus $g_1(a/b)=g_1(a)g_1(1/b)=g_2(a)g_2(1/b)=g_2(a/b)$. Since $a/b$ was arbitrary, this shows that $g_1=g_2$, as desired, so that $\iota$ is indeed an epimorphism. Note that this also provides a counterexample to the question in your post, since $\mathbb{Q}$ has a multiplicative identity even though $2\mathbb{Z}$ does not.